# In Jq how to expand a json array of tuples into multiple elements

Tags: python, json, jq

I have this json string

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"1147179697","pt":1439869512969,
   "mc":[ {"id":"1.120040663",
           "rc":[
                  {"atb":[[7.6,35],[7.2,25]],"id":11111},
                  {"atb":[[1.04,100],[1.02,200]],"id":22222}
                ],
           "con":true,
           "img":false}
        ]}
```

and need to extract the atb elements into prices and amounts together with the id:

```
[{
"atb_price": [7.6, 7.2]
"atb_amount": [35, 25]
"atb_id": [11111, 11111]
},
{
"atb_price": [1.04, 1.02]
"atb_amount": [100, 200]
"atb_id": [22222, 22222]
}]
```

So far I have these filter which gets me some of the way there but not quite.
1. Gives a combination of all prices/amounts/ids.

```
(.mc[].rc | map({"prices":.atb[][0], "vol":.atb[][1], "id":.id}))
```

2. The id element remains outside the array.

```
.mc[].rc | map( {"id":.id, "atb": ( .atb | map({ "amount":  .[1],  "price":.[0] }) )[] } )
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Eventually, I modified one of the answers slightly because my json string was more complex than first thought, in some cases, there are *trd* elements to deal with.

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"1147179697","pt":1439869512969,
   "mc":[ {"id":"1.120040663",
           "rc":[
                  {"atb":[[7.6,35],[7.2,25]],"id":11111},
                  {"atb":[[1.04,100],[1.02,200]],"id":22222}
                  {"trd":[[1.04,100],[1.02,200]],"id":22222}
                ],
           "con":true,
           "img":false}
        ]}
```

The solution,

```
(. | del(.mc))
+ (.mc[] | del(.rc))
+ (.mc[].rc[] 
| .id as $id | .ltp as $ltp | .tv as $rtv
| (select(.atl) | (.atl | {"atl.price": map(.[0]), "atl.volume": map(.[1]), "runner.id": map($id)})),
  (select(.atb) | (.atb | {"atb.price": map(.[0]), "atb.volume": map(.[1]), "runner.id": map($id)})),
  (select(.trd) | (.trd | {"trd.price": map(.[0]), "trd.volume": map(.[1]), "runner.id": map($id)}))
  )
```

Comment: What's up with Python tag?

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated that I'm using jq through pyjq. I believe it works as as an interface to jq. The syntax and arguments are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A succinct and straightforward solution:

```
.mc[].rc[]
| .id as $id
| .atb
| { atb_price:   map(.[0]),
    atb_amount:  map(.[1]),
    atb_id:      map($id) }
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**jq** solution:

```
jq '[.mc[0].rc[] | .id as $id | reduce .atb[] as $i 
    ({"atb_price":[], "atb_amount":[], "atb_id": []}; 
     .atb_price += [$i[0]] | .atb_amount += [$i[1]] | .atb_id += [$id])]' jsonfile
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "atb_price": [
      7.6,
      7.2
    ],
    "atb_amount": [
      35,
      25
    ],
    "atb_id": [
      11111,
      11111
    ]
  },
  {
    "atb_price": [
      1.04,
      1.02
    ],
    "atb_amount": [
      100,
      200
    ],
    "atb_id": [
      22222,
      22222
    ]
  }
]
```